# return the i (index) word from string

Tags: c++, string, return

in a given string, a function should return the word number i

```
char* getWord(char str[], int n )
```

so if `str` is `"My,. name is Jeff"`, if I call `getWord( 2 )` the return should be `name`

note that I can not use `string.h`

I tried counting the `' '` or the `'.'` between words, but it can get complicated when there are multiple of these coming one after the other

So what is the proper algorithm to this

Comment: If you use a `stringstream` it is very easy: http://ideone.com/oV6TIZ

Answer (score 0):

you will need an outer loop which counts words, containing two inner loops.  The first inner loop will be skipping whitespace characters.  (The whitespace between words.) The second inner loop will be skipping non-whitespace characters. (The words themselves.)

Answer (score 0):

Use strtok function passing all special chars as delimiters(e.g. ,.""). This way you can tokenize all words, and you can then easily return the word as per passed index.
Let me know if this works.
eg. strtok(str, delim) and so on.